# Can't uninstall GitHub extension in VS2019 16.3

Tags: github, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2019

My GitHub extension is NOT functioning as it did in VS2017. I cannot publish my new app to GitHub. In fact, when I enter my credentials to log onto GitHub via the extension, it still shows offline.

I am trying to uninstall the extension so I can re-install it and see if it fixes itself now that I upgraded to VS 2019 ver 16.3

The uninstall fails and the log file is enormous, don't know where to start. Any else having this issue?

Sample log

```
9/25/2019 10:47:58 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
9/25/2019 10:47:58 AM - -------------------------------------------
9/25/2019 10:47:58 AM - vsixinstaller.exe version:
9/25/2019 10:47:58 AM - 16.3.2099
9/25/2019 10:47:58 AM - -------------------------------------------
9/25/2019 10:47:58 AM - Command line parameters:
9/25/2019 10:47:58 AM - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual  Studio\Installer\resources\app\ServiceHub\Services\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Service\vsixinstaller.exe,/appidinstallpath:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe,/skuName:Pro,/skuVersion:16.3.29318.209,/appidname:Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019,/culture:en-US,/noep,/u:c3d3dc68-c977-411f-b3e8-03b0dccf7dfc,/callingprocessid:27568,/installas:3432
9/25/2019 10:47:58 AM - -------------------------------------------
9/25/2019 10:47:58 AM - Microsoft VSIX Installer
9/25/2019 10:47:58 AM - -------------------------------------------
9/25/2019 10:47:58 AM - Capping recursion at 5 directories in each extension root due to 'default limit'.
9/25/2019 10:47:59 AM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\05tfg4me.dsb\extension.vsixmanifest'
9/25/2019 10:47:59 AM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\0q2cgzzp.oxd\extension.vsixmanifest'
9/25/2019 10:47:59 AM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\3pjlccdc.dkb\extension.vsixmanifest'
9/25/2019 10:47:59 AM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\3rlnrul4.hii\extension.vsixmanifest'
9/25/2019 10:47:59 AM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\5pjz43v4.juo\extension.vsixmanifest'
9/25/2019 10:47:59 AM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\a2vmsqkn.uu2\extension.vsixmanifest'
9/25/2019 10:47:59 AM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\c2ravt4h.jxw\extension.vsixmanifest'
9/25/2019 10:47:59 AM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\Clide\extension.vsixmanifest'
9/25/2019 10:47:59 AM - Found 'C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\PROFESSIONAL\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\ctj4usrr.tj0\extension.vsixmanifest'
...rest removed for brevity
```

**Note:**

I have now upgraded to VS2019 version 16.3.1

Comment: Hi dinotom, any update for this issue? If it still blocks you, feel free to let me know :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're confused about where to start, you can get some help from [issue #1394](https://github.com/github/VisualStudio/issues/1394).

Also in my opinion, to uninstall the extension you can try:

1.Open `Developer command prompt for VS2019` and type `vsixinstaller /uninstall:c3d3dc68-c977-411f-b3e8-03b0dccf7dfc`.(Similar issue suggests us to install new version of the extension first, then run the command, but only step2 is enough for me, you can try both.)

2.Or Uninstall the extension using VS installer instead of Extension Manager.

[image]

I updated my vs to latest VS16.3.1(brand new VS, never install extensions before) and found something interesting. If I  install the Git extension from VS installer like pic above, the newest version I got(Installed tab) is 2.10.4.8063. But if I search the Git extension by `Extensions=>Manage Extensions=>Online`, the latest version is 2.9.1.7781.

I assume maybe the latest 2.10.4.8063 is the one compatible with latest VS16.3.1, so I think for this Git extension, you should uninstall(also you can try command to uninstall) and then reinstall(Tools=>get Tools and Features=>modify to reinstall) it by Installer instead of Extensions manager or from the VS Marketplace website.

Comment: Li... I tried #1, that failed. How do I do #2, if I open Visual Studio Installer I do not see the option to do anything other than update VS and I am already on 16.3.1. What's weird is your option #1 did work on another PC here that I have VS2019 installed on so something is clearly wrong with the install on my main PC

Comment: @dinotom For #2, you should first make sure the installer is updated(several minutes) if it asks you to do, and then you will find  VS2019 in the page, choose More=>Modify=>find the git extension in Individual components, and uncheck the checkbox=>modify to uninstall it..

Comment: Li...Ok #2 process ran and completed, not sure if its uninstalled yet but it completed. Using the installer on visualstudio.github.com...the version to be installed is 2.9.1...how do I Install the version 2.10.4 you referenced? If I go to marketplace, its also 2.9.1

Comment: ...I cant find the version you referenced anywhere (2.10.4) can you provide a link? And installing the extension (2.9.1) from the main site fails, using that method, on VS 16.3.1. It fails with error message, that version (2.9.1) is lower than that required by VS 16.3.1 and to install from VS itself, but doing that via extensions or installer still only tries to install 2.9.1

Comment: Hi, do you use the same way like #2? I mean you can use #2 to completely uninstall it. After that, reinstall it also in this way. Using the vs installer to reinstall it. (more_modify_install the component again)

Comment: you CANNOT install the extension with either method. You get an error that the version is to low. ANYWHERE you try to find the extension to install, it tries installing 2.9.1 BUT VS 2019 VERSION 16.3 or higher needs 2.10... WHERE does one find that to install?